# Very specific case regarding button click

Tags: c#, button, get

I'm in a middle of process of creating utility console app to help me register to certain classes at my university. So far I've made it download website's content and frequently check for specific changes which gives me an information when the given course is full or available to be taken. Like that:

```
WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://usosweb.umk.pl/kontroler.php?_action=katalog2/przedmioty/pokazPrzedmiot&prz_kod=0600-OG-ChH");
request2.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
Stream stream2 = response2.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
string content_2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
string drugi = getBetween(content_2, @"Stan zapełnienia grup:&lt;/b&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;", "&lt;/b&gt; (zarejestrowanych/limit)");

reader2.Close();
response2.Close();

if (drugi != pierwszy)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rejestracja!");
    Console.Beep(3200, 900);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://usosweb.umk.pl/kontroler.php?_action=katalog2/przedmioty/pokazPrzedmiot&prz_kod=0600-OG-ChH");
    pierwszy = drugi;
}
```

The problem is that it still requires my full attention, as I made it only open the website with the registration buttton on and my goal is to make it actually click it automatically after the slot opens.

Few things to note:

- I have to be logged on that website in order to be able to register at the course
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS0C0.jpg <- this is how that button is coded. The chain_ function is named differently with every single refresh
- http://i.imgur.com/tGX5kmy.jpg <- that is how the registration panel looks like. Ideally I want a website to open in a default browser (or somewhere with cache so I am already logged in) and automatically press that button, as it doesn't require additional confirmation.
- links to one of websites at my university are included in the code above so you may have an additional look on how the buton is coded and how that case could be solved.

After all, is that even possible? Am I able to code it through? I'm using C# but some additional snippets of codes in other languagues could be put it, if that will make it easier or possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for this kind of task automation [**Selenium WebDriver**](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) is the best tool

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;


namespace WEBDRIVER
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
      IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
      query.SendKeys("banana");
      query.Submit();

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
      wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.ToLower().StartsWith("banana"); });

      System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);
      driver.Quit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good call, suggesting Selenium!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it straight away.